# Importing Beautiful Racket reader for new language?

Tags: racket, beautiful-racket

I am using [Beautiful Racket](https://beautifulracket.com/) to draft a new DSL, `bleir`, based on s-expressions. I first install a new racket package using the [Master Recipe](https://beautifulracket.com/appendix/master-recipe.html).

```
raco pkg new bleir
cd bleir
raco pkg install
```

I then set up a vestigial reader and expander in the madatory file, `main.rkt`:

```
#lang br/quicklang

(module+ reader
  (provide read-syntax)
  (require br/quicklang))

(provide (rename-out [bleir-expander #%module-begin]))
(define-macro (bleir-expander PARSE-TREE)
  #'(#%module-begin
     (display PARSE-TREE)))
```

I then write a test file, `tyst-bleir.rkt` [intentional misspelling, to sidestep potential problems with the string name "test"]:

```
#lang bleir
42
```

I get a problem:

> ```
> Module Language: only a module expression is allowed, either
>     #lang <language-name>
>  or
>     (module <name> <language> ...)
>  in: 42
> ```

I can fix it in two ways, "disgusting" and "mysterious". First, the disgusting fix, in `tyst-bleir.rkt`:

```
(module tyst-bleir bleir
  42)
```

This works, invoking both the doubly exported reader from `br/quicklang` and my custom expander, displaying `42`.

**QUESTION 1**: the `#lang bleir` syntax is supposed to be *identical* to the verbose `(module ...)` syntax is it not? Why does `#lang bleir` not work to import the reader from `br/quicklang`?

Now, the mysterious fix:

```
#lang s-exp bleir
42
```

This evidently uses an alternative s-exp reader from module (package?) `s-exp` and it's ok, I guess. At least I'm not blocked. HOWEVER, I do not understand why I can't use the reader from `br/quicklang` in the same way.

```
#lang br/quicklang bleir
42
```

> ```
> bleir: unbound identifier in: bleir
> ```

**QUESTION 2**: Why doesn't this work? Can I fix it? If so, how?

Here is another failed attempt, going the other way, trying to import the reader from `s-exp` in `main-rkt`:

```
(module+ reader
  (provide read-syntax)
  (require s-exp))
```

> ```
> main.rkt:11:11: cannot open module file
>   module path: s-exp
>   path: /usr/share/racket/collects/s-exp/main.rkt
>   system error: no such file or directory; rkt_err=3 in: s-exp
>   no package suggestions are available .
> ```

**QUESTION 3:** Why doesn't this work? Can I fix it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

You didn't fully follow the master recipe that you reference. If you continue reading, you will see:

> read-syntax must return one value: code for a module expres­sion, repre­sented as a syntax object. Typi­cally, the converted S-expres­sions from the source file are inserted into this syntax object. This syntax object must have no iden­ti­fier bind­ings. This module code must include a refer­ence to the expander that will provide the initial set of bind­ings when the module code is eval­u­ated. In pseudocode:

```
#lang br
(module reader br
  (provide read-syntax)
  (define (read-syntax name port)
    (define s-exprs (read-code-from port))
    (strip-bindings
     #`(module dsl-mod-name dsl/expander
         #,@s-exprs))))
```

In other words, your `read-syntax` needs to return `(strip-bindings #'(module ...))`.

### Question 2

I think you are confusing "languages that users use" and "languages that language designers use" together.

"languages that users use" are something like `#lang bleir`, `#lang slideshow`, `#lang pollen`, etc. These languages provide constructs to do domain-specific tasks. For example, `#lang slideshow` is a language for creating presentations. `#lang pollen` is a language for creating books.

"languages that language designers use" are a kind of "languages that users use", where the users are language designers. These languages provide constructs to make language creation easier. `#lang br/quicklang` is in this category.

So you, as a language designer, would use `#lang br/quicklang` internally in your `bleir/main.rkt` for constructing a language `bleir`. But your users, who are not language designers, should not need to write (or even be aware of) `#lang br/quicklang`.

---

The master recipe talks about two things: the reader and the expander. In a fully developed language, you would provide both the reader and the expander. `s-exp` can be seen as a convenient hack language to "run" non-fully developed languages that only have the expander, but don't have the reader yet.

So, the reason why `#lang s-exp bleir` works is that you have a functioning expander, so `#lang s-exp bleir` uses your expander but completely ignores your `reader` submodule. The reason why `#lang bleir` doesn't work is that your `reader` submodule is buggy (see Question 1). The reason why `#lang br/quicklang bleir` doesn't work is that it doesn't make any sense for users to write `#lang br/quicklang`.

I suggest that you simply forget about `s-exp` and fix your reader. AFAIK, Beau­tiful Racket didn't really talk about `s-exp`, and if you are following the book, using `s-exp` will simply make you confused.

### Question 3

If you want a technical answer, https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-lang_syntax.html (or more generally https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-reader%29) answers your question:

> Unlike racket, s-exp cannot be used as a module path with require. Although the syntax of language for #lang overlaps with the syntax of module paths, a language is not used directly as a module path. Instead, a language obtains a module path by trying two locations: first, it looks for a reader submodule of the main module for language. If this is not a valid module path, then language is suffixed with /lang/reader. (If neither is a valid module path, an error is raised.) The resulting module supplies read and read-syntax functions using a protocol that is similar to the one for #reader.